# What would be the best code comparison tool in Linux?

Tags: linux, comparison

When I worked for my previous company, I used BeyondCompare to compare directories containing codes. After switching to a new company, I became to use Linux. For the same code comparison purpose, I started using tkdiff. But, the GUI of tkdiff is not as good as BeyondCompare, and it seems that tkdiff cannot compare directories with multiple files. Could anyone suggest what would be the best free source comparison tool I can use in Linux environment?

Answer (score 2):

in my work , I use Meld (http://meldmerge.org/)
best Regards!